Mapping path space $X_f$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$
I am dealing with the homotopy fiber in Top. I am trying to write the following remark:

The homotopy fiber $X_f$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$. This follows
from the definition of fiber product in Top, where
$X_f=\{(x,\gamma):f(x)=\gamma(1)\}\subset X\times \hom(I,Y)$ inherits
the subspace (product) topology. We can deformation retract $X_f$ to
the set $A= \{(x,\gamma_{f(x)})\}$, where $\gamma_{f(x)}$ is the
constant path at $f(x)$. The set $A$ is canonically homeomorphic to $X$, giving a homotopy equivalence.

How can I find the homotopy that they so casually talk about? On wikipedia it says to "just contract paths" as if I had access to a linear homotopy on $X_f$, something like $F(x,\gamma,s)=(x, (1-s)\gamma + s \gamma_{f(x)})$, but what even is addition in this mapping space? Another problem is then the topology on the second component, $\hom(I,Y)$, equipped with the compact open topology. If I were to write a formula for the deformation retract in question,
$$
F:X_f\times I \to X_f
$$
I'd still have to prove its continuity, which seems like the wrong approach since Wikipedia says I can contract paths so casually.
What I thought is if the universal property defining $X_f$ doesn't immediately give me a (unique) homotopy:
]1
But this also doesn't provide a formula for the homotopy.
It is probably a simple fact that I'm missing here, but I just can't see how they can talk about this deformation retract so casually. Thanks for the help in advance!

This is missing context. What map are you taking the homotopy fibre of? It's not generally true that $\operatorname{hofib}(X \xrightarrow{f} Y)$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

The homotopy is given by $F(x, \gamma, s) = (x, \lambda i. \gamma(i(1-s)))$... you know, contracting the paths. I'm not sure what point @BenSteffan is making.

@NaïmFavier I recommend reading up on what a homotopy fibre and what a mapping path space is. This question is about the latter, not the former, and should say so.

Oh yeah, you're right, I assumed $X_f$ referred to the mapping path space.

@BenSteffan You are right about the definition, I was reading an apparently faulty "reference" I found on github, and they call homotopy fiber to the mapping path space, thus the confusion. Another problem I seem to be having is the homotopy that Naïm indicated: in the reference I'm reading (let me know if I should link it here), the map $\xi$ is the endpoint map and not the starting point, but I have little practice in cooking up homotopies so I can't make it so that $F$ is a deformation retract of any sorts. Is it redundant to take $\xi$ to be the starting point map?

@TakenSpark I think it would be good for you to link the reference. As for start- vs. endpoint, there's no uniform convention and it does not affect the result (up to canonical homeomorphism), though one has to be careful to be consistent throughout.

Please do share your reference. We have $\xi(\gamma) = \gamma(1)$ here given your definition of $X_f$. Maybe my contraction is backwards, but the idea is the same.

The reference is: https://r0hilp.github.io/assets/docs/serre_spectral_sequence.pdf - page 5, example 2.8. I am now looking at May's Concise Course, section "Replacing maps by fibrations" and I understand the deformation retract of $X_f$ onto $A$ (providing the homotopy @NaïmFavier mentioned, which I need to memorize); May uses the starting point map, I assume because the homotopy is simpler. I now ask what would the homotopy $F$ be if I chose $X_f = {(x,\gamma)\rvert f(x)=\gamma(1)}$?

For clarity, let's write $J$ for $[0,1]$ as well, and we wish to define a map $F\colon X_f\times J\to X_f$ forming a homotopy from $\mathrm{id}_{X_f}$ to the map $c\colon X_f\to X_f, (x,\gamma)\mapsto (x,\mathrm{const}_x)$.
We will construct $F$ using universal properties. Write $p_1\colon X_f\to X$ and $p_2\colon X_f\to\mathrm{hom}(I,Y)$ for the two projection maps coming from the pullback diagram defining $X_f$. We have a map $$h\colon J\times I\to I, (s,t)\mapsto (1-s)t+s$$ using which we get a morphism
$$
X_f\times J\times I \xrightarrow{p_2\times h} \mathrm{hom}(I,Y)\times I\xrightarrow{\varepsilon}Y,
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the counit of the adjunction $-\times I\dashv\mathrm{hom}(I,-)$. Adjoining, we get a morphism
$$
q_2\colon X_f\times J\to \mathrm{hom}(I,Y),
$$
which by construction is given by $(x,\gamma,s)\mapsto (\lambda t.\gamma((1-s)t+s)$. (Note that no checking of continuity of this formula is needed, as that already follows from the construction.) We also have a map
$$
q_1=p_1\circ\mathrm{proj}_1\colon X_f\times J\xrightarrow{\mathrm{proj}_1}X_f\xrightarrow{p_1}X
$$
and the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_f\times J @>{q_2}>> \mathrm{hom}(I,Y)\\
@V{q_1}VV @VV{\mathrm{ev}_1}V \\
X @>>{f}> Y
\end{CD}
$$
commutes (this is more universal nonsense, with the only concrete input being that $h(-,1)$ is the constant map $J\to I$ on $1$). This gives us our map $F\colon X_f\times J\to X_f$. Since $p_1F=q_1$ and $p_2F=q_2$, we find the explicit formula for $F$ you were looking for, namely $F(x,\gamma,s)=(x,\lambda t. \gamma((1-s)t+s)$. Note that no explicit checking of continuity of this formula was required. It follows from universal nonsense (with only concrete input being that $h(s,0)=s$ and $h(s,1)=1$) that $F$ defines a homotopy from the identity to $c$, so we are done.
